# Xposed NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android, android-source, xposed-framework, xposed

I'm trying to hook that method in com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar class:

```
@Override
    public void onPlaybackStateChanged(PlaybackState state) {
        super.onPlaybackStateChanged(state);
        if (DEBUG_MEDIA) Log.v(TAG, "DEBUG_MEDIA: onPlaybackStateChanged: " + state);
    }
```

My code looks like this:

```
public void handleLoadPackage(final LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
    if (!lpparam.packageName.equals("com.android.systemui"))
        return;
    findAndHookMethod("com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar", lpparam.classLoader,
            "onPlaybackStateChanged", PlaybackState.class, new XC_MethodHook() {
                @Override
                protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                    if (pstate != null) {
                        if (!isPlaybackActive(pstate.getState())) {
                            clearCurrentMediaNotification();
                            XposedHelpers.callMethod(updateMediaMetaData, "true");
                        }
                        mVisualizerView.setPlaying(pstate.getState() == PlaybackState.STATE_PLAYING);
                    }
                }
            });
```

However, it gives NoSuchMethodError:

```
12-24 14:29:10.361 E/Xposed  ( 2775): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar#onPlaybackStateChanged(android.media.session.PlaybackState)#exact
```

Comment: That method is not a member of the `PhoneStatusBar` class. The class holds a `MediaController.Callback` instance named `mMediaListener` which has that method.

Comment: @Mike M. Does it mean that I have to replace mMediaListener with my own implementation?

Comment: I am not at all familiar with the Xposed framework, so I don't know what you can do, or need to do. Anything I could suggest would just be guesswork.

Comment: Anyway, your advice is still very helpful. Thanks!